# Why is the Xcode compiler compiling differently based on comments (and other irrelevant data)

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator

I have had multiple debugging nightmares trying to get the most basic things to work properly. I admit that

I'm definitely a beginner programmer, but I've worked in enough IDEs and with enough languages to know what should and should not be happening.

Today I was having an issue with my touch engine making a testing app. It compiled fine, but there runtime error. Xcode said it came from a fairly long CGPointIsEqualToPoint() if statement. it looked like:

```
if (CGPointEqualToPoint([touch locationInNode:self], [[[touchesArray objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"touch"] locationInNode:self]))
```

I don't want to turn this into a massive story, so to make it short: I spent 15 minutes debugging getting nowhere. All the variables worked, and I was using the functions correctly. I ended up fixing it by cutting the entire implementation file and pasting it back. It worked like a charm. WHAT?

Many other times I have fixed broken code by deleting comments, which shouldn't affect the code at all.

Comment: its a question tied to a rant.

The question is, why is the compiler making these mistakes?

Comment: Sure, but its important to note that my initial question title was edited. The problem has nothing to do with CGPointEqualToPoint.

In multiple attempts to debug in Xcode, I get runtime errors fixed doing useless tasks like deleting comments. I can't understand where the issue could be, expecially when I clean the build and restart Xcode before building.

Comment: In question form, because I'm still being vague (sorry) How come the program will crash via a runtime error, but work just fine after removing a comment and/or retyping identical code?

Comment: It definitely isn't 0x7fffffff's fault, I basically just asked why Xcode was terrible. Which is essentially what I want to know, but even still... ;) I am trying to think of a legitimate question, will update now...

Comment: First off, don't write such long statements.  It's impossible to be sure you got the parens in the right places, and, when you get a runtime error, you can't tell where in the long statement the error occurred.

Comment: Another thing to beware of is that it's pretty easy in Xcode to accidentally drag/drop something -- a few lines of code, entire modules, entire "folders".  I had trouble with this early on, but I've gotten better somehow (better at avoiding accidental contact with the touch pad, perhaps), and it rarely happens anymore.